# Components in Angular2

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, web, brackets

Sorry but I can't understand why my brackets tell me that cannot find these modules in my angular2 project. This is my *app.module.ts* file:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'; 
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'; 
import { AppComponent } from './app.component'; 

@NgModule({ 
 imports: [ BrowserModule ], 
 declarations: [ AppComponent ], 
 bootstrap: [ AppComponent ] 
}) 


export class AppModule { }
```

And brackets say :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBY8P.png

But the most funny is that I was started this project one week ago and all was perfect, but today brackets tell me that cannot find several modules..

So I decided to re-start again my project and I try to follow this page ([NgModules Documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html)) but in the second step brackets tell me that cannot find the modules...

Anybody can help me please? Anybody knows why?

Comment: If you are following along with the tutorial / examples its `'@angular/core';`, you are missing the `@` sign. The same is true for the next line.

Comment: yes, I try with @! too, but Brackets cannot find any module

Comment: Do you have `node_modules` folder in your repo ?

Comment: Yes, but I use an extension for brackets (brackets-file-tree-exclude) that excludes folders like node_modules because the project is too big...  Do you think that maybe that's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete node_module folder and then run

```
npm install
```

To install all the packages again.